# In my query, could I use the result of a parameter to get more info in that query?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Forgive my terribly-worded question but here's some code to explain what I'm trying to do (`slug` and `value` are provided outside this query):

```
const query = `{
  post(slug: "${slug}") {
    content
    createdAt
    id <--- I want this id for my reply query
    slug
  }

  reply(replyTo: "id") { <--- The second query in question
    content
    createdAt
    id
    slug
  }

  user(id: "${value}") {
    username
  }
}`;
```

I *just* got started with GraphQL and I'm loving the fact that I can query multiple databases in one go. It'd be great if I could also perform some "queryception" but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When thinking in terms of GraphQL, it's important to remember that each field for a given type is resolved by GraphQL *simultaneously*.

For example, when your `post` query returns a `Post` type, GraphQL will resolve the `content` and `createdAt` fields at the same time. Once those fields are resolved, it moved on to the next "level" of the query (for example, if `content` returned a type instead of a scalar, it would then try to resolve those fields.

Each of your individual queries (`post`, `reply`, and `user`) are actually fields of the Root Query type, and the same logic applies to them as well. That means there's no way to reference the id returned by `post` within `reply` -- both queries will be fired off at the same time.

An exception to the above exists in the form of mutations, which are actually resolved sequentially instead of simultaneously. That means, even though you still wouldn't be able to use the result of `post` as a *variable* inside your `reply` query, you could use context to pass the id from one to the other if both were mutations. This, however, is very hackish and requires the client to request the mutations in a specific order.

A more viable solution would be to simply handle this on the client side by breaking it up into two requests, and waiting to fire the second until the first one returns.

Lastly, you may consider reworking your schema to prevent having to have multiple queries in the first place. For example, your Post type could simply have a `replies` field that would resolve to all replies that correspond with the returned post's id.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for your insight! I thought about your last point but I didn't want to run the risk of having enormous objects. Plus, I'm enabling editing so I'd theoretically have to update state across several objects. Looks like two queries is the way to go.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's best practice to use variables instead of directly injecting inputs into your query. And if you're tying your queries to component state, Apollo handles that kind of thing very cleanly: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/